# Connecting azure function to a azure webapp from different tenants

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

So, I have this arquitecture in mind

[image]

I want to render a form in a webapp that is residing in my client's resource. This form is to be completed by other third parties and data collected has to be stored into a database. I have an Azure function that has an HTTP trigger that is expecting this data and, from there, it saves this data in a database (also in my client's resource)

I know that the connection between the Azure function and the database can be solved using managed identities from both sides (never done it yet, but there is material about this). Now,
How can I solve the connection between the web app and my function?
I want it to be secure (HTTPs and/or token) and functional.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Try creating a App registration in client tenant and use that `Client id`, `client secret` and `tenant id` to authenticate to function.  check this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad?tabs=workforce-tenant

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you can't use function access keys due to the single page application (since the secrets would otherwise be available on the client). The only viable solution involves the use of App Service [Authentication/Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/security-concepts?tabs=v4&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203#enable-app-service-authenticationauthorization). However, this means that you need an **identity provider** where all your "end users" are registered.

Comment: can you elaborate on the "all your end user are registered" part? the intention is to facilitate the form without to much authentication for the end user. Something to be as clean as possible.

Comment: Given the inherent security constraints of single-page applications, which prevent the exposure of sensitive information to client-side environments, it's imperative for users to authenticate through a reliable identity provider, such as Entra ID or Entra ID B2C. Upon successful authentication, these providers issue tokens that grant users the authorization needed to interact with the designated API or Function, ensuring a secure and controlled access mechanism.